# A question regarding dimensional analysis and a "Planck matrix"?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

Let:

- the speed of light in a vacuum, $c$,
- the gravitational constant, $G$,
- the reduced Planck constant, $\hat{h}$,
- the Boltzmann constant, $k_B$
- the electric constant, $\epsilon_0$

with dimensions $L,T,M,Q,\theta$. We can write those in a "Planck matrix":

$$
A = 
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
 & L & T & M & Q & \theta \\
c & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
G & 3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hat{h} & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\epsilon_0 & -3 & 2 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
k_B & 2 & -2 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right)
$$

For example to get the Planck units, one can invert this matrix :

$$
A^{-1}=
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
-\frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
-\frac{5}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{5}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right)
$$

One eigenvector of $A$ to the eigenvalue $1$ is:
$$w = \left(-1,\,\frac{4}{9},\,\frac{1}{9},\,0,\,\frac{2}{9}\right)$$

Taking the coefficients of this eigenvector as exponents for the physical constants $c,G,\cdots$ we get:

$$\alpha:= \left(\frac{G^4\hat{h}k_B^2}{c^9}\right)^{1/9} \equiv 1.397949 10^{-22} \frac{m}{s^{4/9} kg^{1/9}K^{2/9}}$$

(Of course everything said, only if I do not have a computation error...)

My question is, if there is a physical interpretation of this last quantity?

Is there any literature about properties of this matrix and physical interpretations of these properties?

Also asked here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409641/a-question-regarding-dimensional-analysis-and-a-planck-matrix

Comment: It is routine linear algebra utilized in all [natural unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) systems. You need "bibliography" for it?

Comment: No, I meant if there is a physical interpretation of properties of this matrix. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: It's called nondimensionalization. All natural unit systems implement it.

Comment: There's no real reason $A$ should have interesting eigenvectors.